# Most efficient way to get stats on an entire SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

What I'm looking to do is review our databases and lock down any `auto-shrink` settings, as well as get a handle on which databases/tables are highly fragmented.

Is there a particular script I can run to get a good idea per database?

I know I can run the following on a per table level (SQL Server 2005 at least):

```
DBCC SHOWCONTIG ('DB.TABLE');
```

But what can I run to show me all tables in a database?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For checking fragmentation in 2005/2008 you can use the following script.  You need to set the `@DB` and `@Table` values.  If you define those as `NULL` then it will run on all databases and/or all tables.  If you do a single db make sure you execute in that DB's context (`USE MyDB`).

```
SELECT 
    object_name(IPS.object_id) AS [Table Name], 
    SI.name AS [Index Name], 
        CASE IPS.Index_type_desc
            WHEN 'CLUSTERED INDEX' THEN 'Clustered'
            ELSE 'Non-Clustered'
        END AS 'Index Type', 
    IPS.avg_fragmentation_in_percent as 'Avg Fragmentation (%)', 
    IPS.avg_fragment_size_in_pages as 'Avg Frag Size (pages)',
    IPS.page_count as 'Page Count', 
    IPS.forwarded_record_count as 'Forwarded Records',
    --IPS.avg_page_space_used_in_percent as 'Avg Page Space Used (%)', 
    --IPS.record_count as 'Record Count', 
    --IPS.ghost_record_count as 'Ghost Record Count',
    IPS.fragment_count as 'Fragment Count'
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats
    (
        db_id(@DB), 
        OBJECT_ID(@Table), 
        NULL,
        NULL , 
        'LIMITED'
    ) as IPS
JOIN sys.indexes as SI WITH (nolock) 
    ON IPS.object_id = SI.object_id 
    AND IPS.index_id = SI.index_id
ORDER BY 1,3,5
```

For autoshrink you can just check `master.sys.databases`:

```
select * from master.sys.databases
where is_auto_shrink_on = 1
```

Comment: +1, thanks just what I need. My 'only' however is, I see some databases return no result at all, is that only because they need to have physical stats in the `sys` db?

Comment: @Jakub - yep.  This script also ignores heaps (unindexed tables), so if there are no indexed tables in a DB it won't show up either.