# Odd SQL Server Studio error, but not on SQL Server Express?

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssms, error-handling, client

I'm running a query that I got today from a previous question, and I just noticed an error that only happens when I run this query ON the server (RDC + MS Studio -- not express) vs on my machine which has MS Studio Express.

**Here is the Error:**

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 22
Incorrect syntax near '('.
```

It refers to this line in my script ([full script here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/14554/7215) on DBA):

```
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats
    (
        db_id(@DB),  <---
        OBJECT_ID(@Table),
```

The odd thing is, that **IF** I run this off my local machine, using MS Studio Express AGAINST that same SQL server (dev box), it runs *just fine* and I get results.

**HOWEVER** if I remote into the SQL dev box, and paste the VERY SAME sql into the MS Studio (non-express) it throws that error `msg 102...` above.

I'm scratching my head why that is, my only thought is that the Studio Express is not validating it the same way as the non-studio client?

Here is the version info for the client on the SQL server:

```
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio  9.00.4035.00
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools    2005.090.4035.00
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC) 2000.086.3959.00 (srv03_sp2_rtm.070216-1710)
Microsoft MSXML             2.6 3.0 4.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer         8.0.6001.18702
Microsoft .NET Framework            2.0.50727.3625
Operating System                5.2.3790
```

and my client:

```
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express9.00.4035.00
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC) 6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)
Microsoft MSXML             3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer         8.0.7600.16385
Microsoft .NET Framework            2.0.50727.4963
Operating System                6.1.7600
```

Any ideas?

## **EDIT 1:**

Per @gbn's suggestion I ran the version check on both (`SELECT @@VERSION, @@SERVERNAME`):

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.4035.00 (Intel X86)   
Nov 24 2008 13:01:59   
Copyright (c) 1988-2005 Microsoft Corporation Developer Edition 
on Windows NT 5.2 (Build 3790: Service Pack 2)  

(server name is same -- not posted)
```

## **EDIT 2:**

Per @DaniSQL's suggestion I ran `SELECT compatibility_level FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'DATABASE_NAME'` and the result was `80` (from both SMSS Express and while RDC'd to the box and connected with non Express SSMS)

Answer (score 2):

The remote database has compatibility level 80, which doesn't work with db_id().  [More info on a related StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9318684/incorrect-syntax-near-the-keyword-current-timestamp-but-only-on-one-database/9318720#9318720).

(Just dumping this into an answer from the question comments so it disappears from the Unanswered list of questions.)